# jasmine help, expect not working

Tags: javascript, jasmine

```
//spec

it('check process data to see if it returns correct JSON object', function() {

var dataExpected = [];

    dataExpected.push({
        image : "https://katmou.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/blade_runner.jpeg",
        title : "Harrison",
        id : 1

    });

    expect(dataAfter).toEqual(dataExpected);
});
```

error:

```
[ERROR] :  .  THERE WERE FAILURES!
[ERROR] :  .  ============================================================
[ERROR] :  .  Recap of failing specs:
[ERROR] :  .  ------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] :  .  viewP controller check process data to see if it returns correct JSON object. - Expected [ { image : 'https://katmou.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/blade_runner.jpeg', title : 'Harrison', id : '1' } ] to equal [ { image : 'https://katmou.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/blade_runner.jpeg', title : 'Harrison', id : 1 } ].
```

The data after is identical to what is expected and it is still failing, why?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried using `expect(dataAfter).toMatch(dataExpected);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the `id` property to be `1`, but in the results it is `'1'`.

Comment: Well spotted. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As from the Jasmine 2.0 Doc http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html the `.toEqual` should work for object, but you are passing an array with one object, so it may be different.
Are you sure that **`dataAfter`** is declared the same way?(an obj inside an array)

A different solution could be compare that two array passing them as string with `JSON.stringify()`. 
See: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)